# Jenkins with .net core, angular 8 and postgre

Tags: automation, c#, jenkins, asp.net

My question is related with automation. In our project we are using BackEnd- .Net Core 2.2 (right now in localhost but will be dockerize) FrontEnd- Angular 8 (right now in localhost but will be dockerize) Database - PostgreSQL (dockerized in other machine using url for CRUD) Jenkins- Also dockerized same as Postgre.

Situation is when I save data to db the data also needed to be checked by Jenkins as well. When data saved to db initially status is "Updating". If Jenkins result was failed status will be changed to "Failed" otherwise to "Success". As I know there is already job created in Jenkins and when I make POST request via postman everything is fine. My question is what is the best approach to implement relationship between Postgre - Backend+FrontEnd - Jenkins.

P.S. I never worked with Jenkins and automation also.